# Was ist die Bedeutung von "Nieder-" in "Niedersachsen" und ähnlichen

Tags: etymology

Worauf bezieht sich das Präfix "Nieder-" in "Niedersachsen", "Niederlande" oder "Niederbayern"?
Bezieht es sich auf die geografische Lage oder hat es eine andere Bedeutung?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Das bedeutet in der Regel, dass das so bezeichnete Gebiet tiefer liegt als das Gebiet, das mit der Vorsilbe »Ober-« bezeichnet ist.

Beispiel: Die beiden österreichischen Bundesländer *Niederösterreich* und *Oberösterreich.* Die beiden Länder bildeten gemeinsam das Erzherzogtum *Österreich* (die anderen Bundesländer des heutigen Österreich waren früher eigenständige Herzogtümer, Bistümer etc.) Ein großer Teil der Grenze zwischen beiden Teilen des Erzherzogtums ist der Fluss Enns, das ist ein Zufluss zur Donau, welche ihrerseits beide Bundesländer durchfließt.

Jenes Verwaltungsgebiet, das stromaufwärts entlang der Donau liegt, hieß damals »Österreich ob der Enns.« Das stromabwärts gelegene (und somit tiefer liegende Gebiet) hieß »Österreich unter der Enns.« Die beiden Gebiete sind weitgehend identisch mit den heutigen Bundesländern *Oberösterreich* und *Niederösterreich.*

Auch das Paar *Oberbayern - Niederbayern* ist ein weiterer Beleg dafür. Die höchsten Berge Deutschlands liegen in Oberbayern. Durch Niederbayern verlässt die Donau deutschen Boden, daher befindet sich dort ein deutlich tiefer liegendes Gebiet.

Die Niederlande sind dafür bekannt, dass große Teile des Landes tiefer als der Meeresspiegel liegen.

Auch Obersachsen liegt geographisch höher als Niedersachsen.

---

Auch die Sprachbezeichnungen *Oberdeutsch* und *Niederdeutsch* beziehen sich auf die Seehöhe der Regionen, in denen diese Dialekte gesprochen werden: Oberdeutsch im gebirgigen Süden des deutschen Sprachraums, Niederdeutsch im flachen Norden, der bis zum Meer abfällt.

Comment: Besteht dann ein Unterschied zwischen dem Präfix "Unter-", welches zumindest in Ortsnamen auch häufig als Komplement zu "Ober-" anzutreffen ist?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Auch bei Ortsnamen bedeuten die Vorsätze *Hoch-, Hohen-* (z.B. *Hohenems*) und *Ober-* im Normalfall eine geographisch höhere Lage (auf einem Berg oder Hügel, oder flussaufwärts gelegen) während *Nieder-* und *Unter-* eine tiefere Lage bedeuten (im Tal, flussabwärts). *Mitt-* oder *Mitter-* (z.B. *Mittersill*) bedeutet eine mittlere Lage. Zum Beispiel liegen im Süden der Steiermark entlang des Labillbaches schön hintereinander, im Abstand von kaum 2 km, die Kleindörfer *Oberlabill, Mitterlabill* und *Unterlabill.* ...

Comment: ... Dazu gibt es aber auch viele Ausnahmen. Beispielsweise ist *»Unterberg«* der Name eines Berggipfels in den Ostalpen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: der bayrisch-österreichische Unter*s*berg mit ca. 1900m Höhe hat seinen Namen lt. Wikipedia von "Untern" = "Mittagspause, Zwischenzeit". Der Unterberg in Niederösterreich mit ca. 1350m wird von der in 11,5 km entfernt liegenden Reisealpe (knapp 1400m) dominiert.

Comment: Schöne Volksetymologien, die richtige Lösung mit Hinblick auf Niederlande, Normandie und Nordsee ergibt sich aber erst im Vergleich mit *Nord* und auch das nicht ohne weiteres, da beides keine altererbeten Formen. Nord ist: "From Pre-Germanic \*h₁nŕ̥t(e)ros, from Proto-Indo-European \*h₁ner- (“inner, under”), from \*h₁en (“in”). Compare Ancient Greek ἐνέρτερος (enérteros), νέρτερος (nérteros)." So liegt weiters der Vergleich zu *hinter*, *Hinterland* (backlands) sowie eventuel auch *alt* nahe (vgl. *Ahne*, *Ur-*, *einst*, *erst*, etc), da Nordland wohl Ausgangspunkt germanischer Besiedlung war

Answer (score -5):

Ich kopier einfach mal meinen Kommentar hierher.

Schöne Volksetymologie. Die richtige Lösung mit Hinblick auf *Niederlande, Normandie* und *Nordsee* ergibt sich aber erst im Vergleich mit *Nord* und auch das nicht ohne weiteres, da beides keine altererbeten Formen sind. *Nord* ist: "From Pre-Germanic **h₁nŕ̥t(e)ros*, from Proto-Indo-European **h₁ner-* (“inner, under”), from **h₁en* (“in”). Compare Ancient Greek *ἐνέρτερος* (*enérteros*), *νέρτερος* (*nérteros*)." So liegt weiters der Vergleich zu *hinter, Hinterland* (backlands) sowie eventuel auch *alt* nahe (vgl. *Ahne, Ur-, einst, erst,* etc), da Nordland wohl Ausgangspunkt germanischer Besiedlung war – (Vectory Dec 26, 2020 at 21:50)

Die Rekonstruktionen berufen sich auf en.wiktionary.

Der Ansatz bedürfte weiterer Erläuterung.

1. **Die Volksetymologie** beginnt mit römischer Besatzung der Germania Superior, der gegenüber die unbesatzten Gebiete als Germania Inferior anzusprechen sind. Die lateinische Etymologie ist hier unbeachtlich. Die Morphologie folgt noch.
2. **Reineweg zufällig** und doch Ausschlaggebend ist, was der Kommentar unterschlagen hat, nämlich *nieder-* gleichwohl auf *ni- "down" zurückzuführen.

   Ob das mit **h₁en*, **h₁ner-* (“inner, under”) zusammenhängt, ist nicht mit Sicherheit zu beurteilen, scheint nur wegen der Semantik und Konsonanz ein attraktiver Schluss.

   *Inferus* "lower" verhält sich jedenfalls [irregulär](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4545/why-does-inferus-have-f-rather-than-d), so wie Meisner argumentiert hat, "that *d<sup>h</sup> underwent treatment as if in anlaut because *en was metanalysed as the preposition *'in'* and **d<sup>h</sup>ero-* as a separate stem", vgl. gothisch *undar*, althochdeutsch *untar* usw. (*apud* de Vaan), obwohl ein solcher Stamm anderweitig nicht ersichtlich ist. Das ist zwar unsicher.

   Zur Anschauung sei bspw. auf die Idiomatik der Präposition *unten* ***im*** *Tal* verwiesen. *n- soll wohl nullstufiger Ablaut von *h₁en- chronologisch nach wegfall der Laryngeale sein.

   Zwar hat *nieder* mit Sanskrit *nitarā́m* "niederwärts, nach unten" eine genaue Entsprechung in ie. **nitero-* mit einem üblichen Ableitungssuffix (DWDS), auf den auch *Norden* aufbaut. Allerdings wird die Entstehung der Kontrastiven Adjektive relativ spät in der indogermanischen Entwicklung angesetzt (...) und Sanskrit ist nicht unbedingt am ältesten nur weil es sich am weitesten entfernt hat. Dort heißt es ganz richtig *Uter Pradesh* (kleines Paradies? Vgl. "Sogdia" im Japanischen als Homographie für Paradies).

   Altkirchenslavisch *nizъ* "nieder, hinab, unten" und Homer'sches griechisch *né͞iatos* (νείατος) "unterster, äußerster", "eine Art unregelmäßiger superl. zu νέος" (Pape, lsj.gr) zeigen das Suffix nicht. Im Gegenteil wäre der dazugehörige Superlativ wie *super, supra, supremum* wohl **-(t)mHo-* (vgl. *imus* "lowest, deepest, innermost).
3. ***Andere* Vergleiche*** sind regmäßig fernzuhalten.

   "Hinterland" gilt wie "marshland", "Grenzgebiet" usw. nur zur Veranschaulichung; nicht zu verwechseln mit *Inter Mailand*.

   *Alt* ist auf den Wechsel derjenigen Wurzel **h2el-* gegenüber **h2en-* mit den Ableitungen *alias* "anderer" respektive *an-derer* bezogen. Zudem entspricht die *Unterwelt* in poetischer Sprache *otherworld*, sowie *inferi* ~ *-orum* "the inhabitants of the underworld", was zumindest in Sumero-Akkadischer Literatur auch in Richtung ca. Westen geht.

   Daran könnte *urlaub* zwar anschließen, vgl. engl. *furleave* gegen lat. *feria*, bzw. hier die *Erlaubnis sich zu entfernen* (weiteres bei Grimm). Obwohl *foreign* zwar weder mit *ur-*, *fremd* noch *fern* zu vergleichen ist, sondern *outdoors*, steht es darin aber noch am nächsten bei besagtem ghostword **d<sup>h</sup>ero-*. Heureka!

   Hinter *eins*, Proto-Indo-Europäisch *Hoy-nos mag eine Ableitung von **h₁e-* vermutet werden, doch das äußerst dünne Eis ist nicht belastbar. Englisch *yon, yonder*, *the beyond* (wie *otherworld*) gehört wahrscheinlich dazu, mag Zufall sein.
4. ***Nord*** ist außergermanisch jedenfalls unbekannt. Latein benützt dafür *borealis*, ein Nordwind der griechischen Mythologie, zur Bezeichnung der Himmelsrichtung, ohne Etymologie. Es ist dafür zweckmäßig, einen vergessenen Verwandschaftsgrad zu vermuten ...

   Einerseits wird verwiesen auf Sanskrit (*giri-*) und Balto-Slavisch (Litauisch *girė,* Old Church Slavonic *gora*) "mountain" (auch "forest") als ob "those living beyond the mountains." (etymonline) Eine entsprechende Vergleichsmöichkeit findet sich schon im Sumerischen (cf. epsd sux. *gilim*, akk. *gūru* "foliage", auch "forest") im Wechsel mit anlautendem *m* (wimre.).
5. **Andererseits** ist für die Toponomastik *Nehrung* beachtlich, was mit *narrow* "eng" wiederum zu *Angeln*, und *Vikingern passen sollte (s. dort), andererseits jedoch an *Meer*, *Meereszunge* erinnert.

   Zieht man zum weiteren Vergleich *naos*, ahd. *nacho* "Schiff" und englisch *boat* heran, um *boreas* mit *Nord* ... wird man vergeblich nach dem kleinsten gemeinsamen Nenner suchen. Tamil *kattumaram* (Katamaran*) als dritter im Bunde führt mit *kaṭṭu* "Band, Bündel" und *maram* "Baum" (DWDS, was ich nach erster Suche in DSAL kaum bestätigen kann) definitiv zu weit, auch wenn mit Sumerisch schon Meluhha im Blick ist, und *catina* "Kette" (wie "Band"?) ein bekanntes mediterranes Wanderwort ist, sowie griechisch *kata* auch "herunter" bedeutet. Das eine begründet das andere leider nicht.

   Man darf im Ansatz */n m b/ wenigstens auf *Mark* verweisen, insbesonder die *Mark Brandenburg*, vieleicht auch *Mecklenburg* (das wäre nieklich), denn an jener Stelle wird die germanische Urheimat verortet (passim, trotz dürftiger Beweislage). Widerum im Alpenraum werden inzwischen die Anfänge der Runenschrift gesucht (Helm von Negau) was für die Onomasiologie relevant ist.

Wegen der dürftigen Quellenlage in niederdeutschem Gebiet ist die Toponomastik letztendlich unsicher und die angesprochenen Bedeutung gar nicht zu falsifizieren.

---

**PS:** Der Vergleich ist tatsächlich nicht ganz neu, nur fehlt eine formale Lösung zur Verwandschaft der nunmehr gertennt behandelten *ni- und *h1en. Grimm gab dereinst zu bedenken:

> — *über die etymologie des wortes gibt es nur vermutungen: das schon von Wachter 1148 verglichene griech.* νέρτερος *(unten, weiter unten befindlich) wird auch von Wackernagel im handwb. 215ᵇ und von L. Meyer in den bemerkungen z. ältesten gesch. der griech. myth. 55 beigezogen, wozu nun Kluge im etymol. wb. 241ᵇ noch zu bedenken gibt, dasz das umbrische nertro 'links' bedeutet, so dasz wir also hier wieder wie in andern sprachen der vorstellung begegnen würden, dasz links und rechts auch zugleich die begriffe nördlich und südlich ausdrücken (s. Grimm gesch. d. d. spr. 980 ff., vergl. auch dessen kl. schriften 4, 258 f. myth.⁴ 28, 836, nachtr. 22. 295, rechtsalterth. 808); Weinhold in Haupts zeitschr. 6, 460 (vergl. auch dessen riesen 25) stellt es mit* Niörđr, Neri, nerge *(s.* nehrung*) und* norne *zu sanskr.* nâra, nîra *wasser, griech.* νᾱρός, νηρός *flieszend (das schon von Graff 2, 1096 verglichen wurde), so dasz sich etwa als grundbedeutung 'meerwärts liegende gegend' oder (mit bezug auf den wind) 'vom meere herkommend' ergeben würde.* (dwds/dwb: Nord)

Das war eigentlich recht einfach aufzustöbern, um nicht zu sagen offensichtlich. Für die aufsässigen Kommentatoren (unten) ist es aber zu viel verlangt oder zu unwissenschaftlich; zu recht, dennoch unbegründet, wie ich finde, weil ich nur behaupte, die Etymologie sei unsicher, sie sich aberwitziger Weise in Sicherheit wiegen, *bitte gehen Sie weiter, es gibt hier nichts zu sehen*.

Comment: Ich lese hier einiges mit fragwürdigem Wahrheitsgehalt über *"hinter" und "Nord", sogar über *"alt", "Urlaub", "Nehrung", "Katamaran"* und *"Mark"*, und dabei frage ich mich die ganze Zeit: Hat du die Frage überhaupt gelesen? Hast du sie auch verstanden? Denn nichts von dem, was du hier hinterlassen hast beantwortet die gestellte Frage.

Comment: Ich habe -1 auf diesen diesen Text gegeben, weil er meiner Meinung nach pseudowissenschaftliches Geschwafel ist. *(Ich sage hiermit nichts nichts über den Autor. Ich sage etwas über meine Meinung, die ich zu diesem Text habe.)*

Comment: @Alina welcher Teil davon ist denn pseudowissenschaftlich? Ernst gemeinte Frage.

Comment: @CorneliusBrand: Alles. Ich kann nicht beurteilen, was von dieser Antwort frei erfunden und was wahr ist. Und ich glaube, dass kaum ein anderer Leser dieses Forums dazu in der Lage sein wird. Warum muss man sich auf Altgriechisch, Sanskrit, Altkirchenslawisch und Sumerisch berufen, um diese Frage zu beantworten? Diese Antwort ist pseudowissenschaftlich, denn sie gibt vor, wissenschaftlich zu sein, zitiert aber keine einzige Quelle. Vor allem aber produziert diese Antwort eine Menge heiße Luft. Diese Antwort schießt mit Kanonen meilenweit an den Spatzen vorbei.

Comment: jener Kommentar enthält einmal alles, *harrasment* (ist jetzt das drölfte mal die gleiche Leier), *bigotry* ("Ich kann nicht beurteilen ...", "Warum muss man ...", "... keine einzige Quelle") und *abuse* (oder *name-calling*, wie es im CoC heißt). Die vergleichende Sprachwissenschaft auf die ich mich berufe, welcher ich meine noch etwas hinzuzufügen habe, ist jetzt also Pseudowissenschaf? Natürlich bevorzugt die Komparativistik zeitgenössische Quellen ersten Grades, die ich kategorisch ausgeschlossen habe, auch weil Hubertus Antwort nicht die angemessene Vorarbeit geleistet hat,

Comment: […] die übrigens gar keine wissenschaftliche Quelle enthält und damit doch ganz gut fährt. Wenn das also als *offensichtlich* dahingestellt werden kann, ist das genauso akzeptabel, wenn ein Nachweis für die Aussage, dass *Nord* in der Betrachtung von *nieder* bisher nicht beachtet wird, Prinzip bedingt. Die Gründe, die regelmäßig dagegen sprechen würden, sind ebenso anachronistisch. Um das nachzuvollziehen, müsste die Beschwerdeführung sich ein wenig auf dem Gebiet auskennen. Ohne dies ist die Beschwerde unerheblich und dahingehend nicht kooperativ.

Comment: *Die vergleichende Sprachwissenschaft auf die ich mich berufe, welcher ich meine noch etwas hinzuzufügen habe […]* Das Nachschlagen von Etymologien auf Wiktionary und Zusammenstellen von Ähnlichklingendem ist kein Beitrag zur Wissenschaft. Was wichtiger ist: Es hilft auch den Fragestellern nichts. Die Behauptung, daß die *Niederlande* die Nordlande wären, ist ja noch nicht einmal ordentlich aufgeschrieben (aber wie soll man denn Altniederländisch *north* und *nither* verwechseln?).

Comment: Alles andere, die irrelevanten Belege, der Schreibstil (*Andere Vergleiche sind regmäßig fernzuhalten*), die gespielte Empörung … ist nur Ablenkung von der Tatsache, daß du diese Seite mißbrauchst, in der es um Antworten auf Fragen geht, und nicht um private etymologische Träumereien.

Comment: "Zusammenstellen von Ähnlichklingendem ist kein Beitrag zur Wissenschaft." Natürlich, doch, insbesondere wenn man sich auf der Zunge zergehen lässt, was *ähnlich* bedeutet. Ob eure Meinung, die Worte ähnelten sich nicht, von meiner abweicht, bestätigt gleichfalls meine Aussage, dass der Vergleich sonst nicht gezogen wird, sowie eure Aussage, die wiederum meine Vermutung bestätigt, dass ihr die Bedeutung der Etymologie nicht mal im Traum erahnen können wollen würdet. Das ist keine Träumerei, das ist ein Albtraum. Das ist keine gespielte Empörung, sondern sachdienlich, emporkömmliches Wortspiel.

Comment: Ich bin kein Sprachwissenschaftler, aber mit römischer Geschichte kenne ich mich etwas aus. Sowohl Germania Superior als auch Germania Inferior sind Verwaltungseinheiten innerhalb des römischen Herrschaftsbereichs.

Comment: @Lykanion, zu Zeiten des Friedens ist die Identifizierung einfach. Das Gebiet war aber lange umkämpft, wurde Provinz in 89, nachdem bspw. Aulus Vitellius, der, wie Tacitus später berichtet, als General der Truppen zu Germania Inferior berufen gewesen ist, doch schon 69 ermordet worden war. Jedenfalls sollte man Inferior nicht mit Germania Magna verwechseln. So genau lässt sich das sicheich nicht trennen, weil Cesar bspw. noch ganz einfach von Germania schreibt. http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=Germani

Comment: @Alina Dass die Antwort hier etwas verzwirbelt ist, steht, glaube ich, außer Frage. Insofern kann ich gut verstehen, dass man sich daran stößt. Was mich aber stutzig macht, ist, dass die Antwort von Hubert so allgemein auf Zuspruch stößt, nachdem ja auch hier überhaupt nicht beurteilbar ist, ob sie denn nun stimmt oder nicht. Ich kann vectory's Kompetenz in historischer Sprachwissenschaft nicht beurteilen, aber wenn man sich einer Frage unvoreingenommen nähert, stellt man oft fest, dass selbst einfache Fragen schwierig ohne Rückgriff auf "weil das doch klar ist" zu beantworten sind. Darum...

Comment: ...bin ich geneigt, dieser Antwort wenigstens einen mahnenden zweiten Platz neben Huberts zuzugestehen, sozusagen als 'memento errare.' Vielleicht scheint hier meine Mathematikerseele hervor, für die sogar Aussagen wie "0 ist kleiner als 1" eines echten Beweises würdig und v.a. bedürftig sind (kein Witz, siehe z.B. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458288/proof-zero-is-less-than-one). Insofern ist es für mich _a priori_ nicht klar, dass stimmt, was Hubert sagt, bzw. nicht stimmt, was vectory sagt (der seine Gedanken, zugegeben, allerdings verworren darstellt).